# Best practices for importing multiple components from react-bootstrap?

Tags: react-bootstrap

For performance reasons the **React-Bootstrap** documentation suggests importing individual components rather than the whole library. So:

```js
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
```

instead of

```js
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

My question is whether there is a limit to this when importing numerous components? i.e.

```js
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import ProgressBar from 'react-bootstrap/ProgressBar';
import Popover from 'react-bootstrap/Popover';
import OverlayTrigger from 'react-bootstrap/OverlayTrigger';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Badge from 'react-bootstrap/Badge';
```

as opposed to:

```js
import { Alert, Row, Col, ProgressBar, Popover, OverlayTrigger, Button, Badge } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Is there still such a performance gain that it's better to have the individual `import` statements, or is there a cutoff that others follow, where more than a certain number of components gets included in one line instead of multiple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use named imports and tree shake not used code. For example with Create-React-App tree shaking is automatically configured. Then using

```
import { Alert, Row, Col, ProgressBar, Popover, OverlayTrigger, Button, Badge } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

is in the end the same as

```
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import ProgressBar from 'react-bootstrap/ProgressBar';
import Popover from 'react-bootstrap/Popover';
import OverlayTrigger from 'react-bootstrap/OverlayTrigger';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Badge from 'react-bootstrap/Badge';
```

To anwser your question directly: Yes, it always better to get rid of not used code. Even if you use ten components from react-bootstrap - this library has A LOT more and I can't imagine a single component where you would use even 70-80% of them.

Comment: Thanks for this! Tree shaking is a good factor to consider -- the code is more readable, and the problem of unused code goes away.

Comment: You gave him the wrong answer, He should use the export default one even Bootstrap said so it is not the same! 

Tree shaking is not entirely reliable. This article provides insight on why that's the case: https://advancedweb.hu/2017/02/07/treeshaking/